# Installing `terra` or `sf` R package using Conda

Tags: r, conda, gdal, r-sf, terra

I would like to install the `terra` or `sf` R package in a Conda environment (on a Linux HPC). The following error appears if I install it from within R:

```r
# remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")
# or
# install.packages("terra")
```

```r
Downloading GitHub repo rspatial/terra@HEAD
── R CMD build ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpaqfEN6/remotes89835435cd48/rspatial-terra-2237fa5/DESCRIPTION’ (442ms)
─  preparing ‘terra’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  running ‘cleanup’
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (476ms)
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘terra_1.7-64.tar.gz’
   Warning: file 'terra/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warning: file 'terra/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warning: invalid uid value replaced by that for user 'nobody'
   Warning: invalid gid value replaced by that for user 'nobody'

Installing package into ‘/pfs/****/users/****/R/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
** using staged installation
configure: CC: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc
configure: CXX: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++17
checking for gdal-config... /****/miniconda/envs/env1/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 3.8.1
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.1... yes
checking for gcc... x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... no
checking GDAL: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no
/****/miniconda/envs/env1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /****/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawnp@GLIBC_2.15'
/****/miniconda/envs/env1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /****/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/****/miniconda/envs/env1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /****/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `posix_spawnp@GLIBC_2.15'
/****/miniconda/envs/env1/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /****/miniconda/envs/env1/lib/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure: Install failure: compilation and/or linkage problems.
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘terra’
* removing ‘/pfs/****/users/****/R/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-library/4.3/terra’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpaqfEN6/file8983693cdcc5/terra_1.7-64.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was able to install these packages if I added them to the Conda configuration file; e.g.:

```yaml
 - r-sf
 - r-terra
```

However, I need to be able to install the development version from GitHub. This is a snippet from my configuration file:

```yaml
name: R_Conda
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - anaconda
dependencies:
 - r-base=4.3.2
 - proj
 - geos
 - gdal
 - fontconfig-devel-cos7-aarch64
```

Any advice on how to avoid this error:

```bash
configure: error: GDALAllRegister not found in libgdal.
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the development version of `terra`? Terra released v1.7-65 in the last 24 hours and it built without a hitch on Conda Forge (been available for ~ 6 hours). Is there a specific version of `sf` that is missing?

Comment: I am not interested in the development version of `terra` per se, but the ability to install/update both packages from within R using `install.packages` or `devtools::install_packages` without the need to re-create the Conda environment. The problem is that I can install these packages while installing a new Conda environment but can not install them from within R.

Comment: If it fails on the linker step, I exit the conda environment and re-run make. It will finish the linking against the new-fangled, gcc symbols. (Apparently gcc now substitutes `memcpy`, `memove`, and a few other symbols to work around earlier bugs).